# In what context would I use 见怪不怪?

Tags: idioms

怎么用见怪不怪? 请给我一个例子。谢谢！
Could I use this idiom do describe another culture that once seemed foreign? Also, does the idiom have good or bad connotations?

Comment: 参考爱词霸词典,consult iciba

Comment: **见**过的**怪**事多了，也就**不**觉得奇**怪**了。one would not surprised by the strange things that had seen much more times.

Answer (score 2):

**Oxford** uses the word *inured*, which should give you an idea of the negative connotations attached to it.

> not be surprised by anything unusual
>
> 对腐败见怪不怪, 腐败就难以根除。
>
> If we become inured to corruption, we won't be able to wipe it out.

**Adsotrans** defines it as

> to be totally jaded

Which is a good way of understanding the feelings behind 见怪不怪.

Here's an example sentence from a Chinese Chengyu dictionary

> 他的行为开始令人觉得怪异,但时间一长,人们也就见怪不怪了｡
>
> His behavior made people feel most peculiar, but after a while, everyone stopped seeming to notice.

Answer (score 1):

It means 'to get used to something unusual', 'to get to bear something unbearable'.

---

From [iciba.com](http://www.iciba.com/%E8%A7%81%E6%80%AA%E4%B8%8D%E6%80%AA):

在警队呆了40年后，我对什么都见怪不怪了。

After 40 years in the police, nothing shocks me anymore.